# ImageJ package for R

Tags: r, image-processing, imagej

I'm looking for an integration of ImageJ and R. There was a package called RImageJ as referenced in [1][2] for previous versions of R (I'm using R 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet" ) but it isn't available anymore.

Basically what I'd like to try is a region growing algorithm over an image in R. Does anybody know about an updated version of RImageJ or another package allowing this algorithm?.

Thanks ;)

[1] http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?category/R-package/RImageJ
[2] http://cmci.embl.de/documents/101105ij_r_jython#using_imagej_from_r

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning

Comment: Unfortunately I think the problem is not related with the repo or typos, the package existed just for linux and it was archived as one can see in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RImageJ/index.html, in any case is a useful info! Thanks John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bio7](http://bio7.org/) project is a version of ImageJ which features integration with R, among other improvements.

It is also worth mentioning that the [ImageJ2 project](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) has a project under development called [scripting-r](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-r), which seeks to provide a JSR-223-compliant scripting language built on top of [RServe](http://rforge.net/Rserve/). However, it is not yet functional. Once it is, it will be possible to execute R code as a script from within ImageJ's [Script Editor](http://imagej.net/Script_Editor).

Edit 2016-09-26: As of this writing, the SciJava `scripting-r` project is now built on [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/), an implementation of R on top of the JVM. Huzzah!

Comment: Thank you very much ctrueden, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the pixmap package to do image processing in the past, but it's pretty bare-bones. It might also be worth looking into the package geomorph.

Comment: I've reviewed the packages without finding region growing algoritmh but thank you very much for refering  them CactusW :)