# Controlling other softwares from R interfase (imageJ)

Tags: r, imagej

### The problem

I am trying to develop a package in R to control ImageJ, I have seen several R packages that develop an R interface from R to another package, I haven found the slightest documentation on how to start developing that

#### Edit

Thanks to for the coment, I had seen the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352595/imagej-package-for-r) about RimageJ and bio7, but I would really like to learn to control other softwares from R.

#### Examples

- [RNetlogo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNetLogo/index.html)
- [rPython](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html)
- [rJava](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352595/imagej-package-for-r

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck I had seen that question before, but I have had this problem before where I need to control another package from R and I would like to learn how to do it